# How to exclude a route from displaying the root layout in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, routes, layout

I have a route that I don't want it to display the header that is in the root layout.

I tried to check for the name of the component that is rendering in the root layout, so if it is the one that I do not want it to contain the header the root layout will be empty, but this did not work, I think the way I used to know the component name was not correct.

Comment: [Route group](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups) - in your root you'd have a layout w/o the header, in a group you'd have the layout with the header. There are a few ways to handle this, look at the docs for layouts.